# Concurrent program does not terminate

Tags: c++

I have the following concurrent program:

```
template <typename T>
class CircularBuffers{
public:
    CircularBuffers(const T &size):_buffer(size),_start(0),_end(0){
        assert((size > 1 && "size must be greater than 1"));
    }

    CircularBuffers(std::initializer_list<T> l):_buffer(l),_start(0),_end(l.size()-1){}

    void addValue(const T &value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(_mutex);
        _end = (_end+1) % _buffer.size();
        if (_end==_start){_start = (_start+1) % _buffer.size();}
        _buffer[_start] = value;
    }

    T poll()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock(_mutex);
        _read_cond.wait(uLock,[&](){return !isEmpty();});
        T element = _buffer[_start];
        _start = (_start + 1) % _buffer.size();
        return element;
    }

    bool isFull(){
        return _start == (_end+1) % _buffer.size();
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return _start == _end;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _buffer;
    int _start;
    int _end;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _read_cond;
};


int main()
{   
    std::shared_ptr<CircularBuffers<int>> circ = std::make_shared<CircularBuffers<int>>(7);
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures_add;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> futures_poll;

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        futures_add.emplace_back(std::async(&CircularBuffers<int>::addValue,circ,i));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        futures_poll.emplace_back(std::async(&CircularBuffers<int>::poll,circ));
    }
    std::for_each(futures_add.begin(),futures_add.end(),[](std::future<void> &ftr){ftr.wait();});
    std::for_each(futures_poll.begin(),futures_poll.end(),[](std::future<int> &ftr){ftr.wait();});
}
```

It never ends and it is because of the concurrency but I cannot manage to see why.
My questions are:

- Why does not end? It goes over the first set of waits but for the waits from poll it gets stacked.
- How could I adapt this code to make it work forever, in the sense that an infinite while for writing and polling is created BUT every time a thread gives a result, it gets deleted to leave space to new thread in the respective future vector, in order not to end up creating infinite threads.

Comment: So did you try debugging your program to see where it stops? Did you try "duck debugging" - placing `std::cout` in various places in the program to discover where does it stop? You `wait` on `condition_variable`, yet you never notify it. I guess I advise to make sure you took a closer look at `_read_cond.wait` and how `std::condition_variable::wait` works.

Comment: sorry you are right I should add more info, Ill edited

Comment: VictorSanchez did you notice" **You wait on condition_variable, yet you never notify it**" in the remark  of @KamilCuk ?

Comment: Oh you right, thanks a lot man, sorry for the silly question

Comment: Don't fix the problem in the question please

Comment: its not fixed still. Something else is missing

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Sorry, I have solve it already, you are right